# Mutating Object property giving the preserved value not the modified one

Tags: javascript, object

I was playing around with the JavaScript objects by mutating the property values and find this observation.

**Problem statement:** I am mutating an object property value inside a function and returning the object but somehow it preserved the previous value and not giving the updated one.

```js
const obj = { prop: 5 }

const mutatingObjectFunction = () => {
  let temp = obj.prop;
  obj.prop = 10;
  return temp;
}

console.log(mutatingObjectFunction()); // 5
```

Why it is returning 5 and not 10?

If I will assign directly an object instead of its property to a temp variable, then it is giving me the updated value.

```js
const obj = { prop: 5 }

const mutatingObjectFunction = () => {
  let temp = obj;
  obj.prop = 10;
  return temp;
}

console.log(mutatingObjectFunction().prop); // 10
```

Why is this behaving differently while passing a whole `object` or a object `property` in a `temp` variable ?

Comment: Define `temp = obj.prop` after you assign `obj.prop = 10`;

Comment: @zer00ne In that case it will give me the updated one but my question is why it is not giving the mutated value in the above code snippet. Why it is behaving differently in both the code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a primitive property by reference in JS. So what you're passing to `temp` isn't `obj.prop`, but just `5`.

But when you pass an object, you're passing a refernce to that same object instance so mutating that object can reflect in all references to it.

```js
let testObj = [] // Arrays are objects too

let a = {obj : testObj}
let temp = a.obj // temp is now a reference to the same array

a.obj.push(1)
temp.push(2)

console.log(temp)
```

```js
let a = {obj: {value: 5}} // We use an object, {value: 5}
let temp = a.obj // temp is now a reference to our object
a.obj.value++
temp.value++
console.log(temp.value) // 7
```

Answer (score 1):

As per JavaScript here
`let temp = obj;`
you or not cloning the `object` you referencing a `object`. If you want to clone the `object` you should use Spread operator like this `let temp = {...obj};`

As per you second example you are referencing a object. so if you changed the actual object value it's also affect referenced `temp` value

But in the first example you are not assigning complete `object` instead you assigning a particular value of the object. so here you making a coping the value `let temp = obj.prop;`. so it won't affected when the actual value is changed